# Выкидывает из скомпилированного файла (Pascal)

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

После каждого скомпилированного кода у меня просто выкидывает из консоли после того как я ввожу число. По советам многих вставил 'readln'. Не помогло. Может кто сталкивался с такой проблемой? Кто может помочь? Скрины предоставляются.
[image: Редкий кадр. Успел заскриншотить до того как она моментально вырубилась]

```
`var
  a, b, c: integer;
begin
  write('Введите числа a и b: '); 
  read(a, b);
 while b <> 0 do
  begin
    c := a mod b;
    a := b;
    b := c;  
    write ('НОД равно ', a);
  end;
  readln();
  end.`
```

Comment: консоль кстати я успел сриншотнуть когда она сразу закрылась (она моментально закрывается)

Comment: Попробуйте два раза написать `readln(); readln();` Или без скобок `readln;`

Comment: подряд? друг за другом?

Comment: СПАСИБО ПОМОГЛО!

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста :)

Comment: да и еще как можно сделать так, чтобы можно было вводить числа до бесконечности. Когда я ввожу какие-то числа в консоль потом другие, у меня она закрывается. Если и с этим поможешь то цены тебе не будет!!

Comment: Неужели опять крошки в клавиатуре? :)

Comment: да все очень плохо

Comment: @ArmenEpremyan, разве что вводить строку.. Вы не сможете вводить большое число, которое выходит из-за границу максимального значения типа.

Comment: нет я имею ввиду например ввел 12 и 2. Потом захотел ввести 14 и 7, а тогда уже консоль закрывается. Как такое предотвратить.

Comment: Циклом... например,  `repeat ... until`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Тогда уж так:

```
var
  a, b, c: integer;

function NOD(a, b:integer):integer; // Универсальная функция нахождения наибольшего общего делителя, можно упростить, поскольку проверка на 0 идёт в теле программы
begin
   If a<>0 then NOD:= NOD(b mod a,a) else NOD:= b;
End;

begin
  writeln('Программа считает НОД двух чисел');
  writeln('Введите числа a и b (программа завершится, когда одно из введенных чисел будет равно нулю, или вы нажмёте Ctrl+C): ');
  repeat
     write('Введите a:'); Readln(a);  // можно и так readln(a,b); тогда в одну строку надо вводить 2 числа
     if a=0 then break;
     write('Введите b:'); Readln(b);
     if b=0 then break;
     writeln ('НОД равно ', NOD(a,b));
  until false;
end.
```